# How to get variable from CMD input?

Tags: php, cmd

Currently I develop a system get response from API. This project required can I/O with CMD. Example command like `php my-file.php "variable=100"`. I would like to know how to get the value from variable

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


function paramFromCmd($test) {
return $test;
}
print_r(paramFromCmd($argv));
```

From cmd:

```
php test.php "Hello world"
```

Output:

Array

```
(
[0] => test.php
[1] => hello world
)
```